# Create Node with an integer as property with Neo4j REST API

Tags: json, node.js, neo4j

I'm currently working a Neo4j REST API wrapper for nodejs (node-neo4j).
Just making it ready for v2.0 of Neo4j

My fork: https://github.com/Stofkn/node-neo4j of https://github.com/philippkueng/node-neo4j

Is it possible to use the REST API to create a node with an integer like:
{ name: 'Kristof', age: 77 }

It creates a Node like this { name: 'Kristof', age: '77' }

Is the only workaround a Cypher query or a server plugin?

Comment: As far as I know, JSON does have types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should create the node with an numeric property, if it doesn't it's a bug but the code for that has been around for a long while.

For 2.0 I'd suggest to focus on the transactional endpoint first and add support for the REST API later on :)

Comment: I tried a request with Postman (chrome Rest Client) http://imm.io/1gwCO but no success. When I change the string to an integer in the admin panel of Neo4j and then request the node it returns an integer. So it could be a bug. I'm not sure.

Comment: It was a bug in superagent. After I updated superagent my code worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Michael.

I had to remove the type 'form' otherwise the integer is interpreted as a string.

My solution for a simple node creation without labels:

```
var request = require('superagent');

request
        .post(this.url + '/db/data/node')
        .send(node) 
     // .type('form') remove this line      
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .end(function(result){
            if(typeof result.body !== 'undefined')
                that.addNodeId(result.body, callback);
            else 
                callback(new Error('Response is empty'), null);
        });
```